# How do I reuse/generalize similar code to optimize performance (.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working on 5 different projects which basically do the same things in the background. 90% of the server side code of all the projects is same (including method names, calls to database). I guess the person before me have copied and pasted the code to achieve the same functionality. Since majority of the code is similar for all 5 projects I am planning to optimize/reuse/generalize the code. For first I thought of creating DLL, but again including DLL in all projects will not make it generalized. I also thought of using WebAPI for the common functions but not sure whether I can achieve my goal. Can you please suggest the best thing that I can do in my scenario.

Comment: "including DLL in all projects will not make it generalized" - including a DLL is exactly how you achieve sharing libraries.

Comment: Make class libraries, deploy to GAC, reference from there.

Comment: If you have common core business logic, you can put it in separate dll. If you have future requirement to expose those logic for other platform as well, you can expose those to API. So, it's entirely depends upon your requirement.

Comment: The short answer to this is; it depends. If you want hyperscalability, then a WebApi might be the way to go. If you want to generalise then creating a dll with generic objects/methods on them that can be extended would be the way to go. You could also take it a step further and put that DLL as a NuGet package on a local server for easy inclusion into your projects.

Comment: I don't think there's enough info to give a clear answer.  It depends on what your code is doing.  Your against a dll/lib being added to each project?

Comment: Since you mentioned of make it a web api, and the code is also having database and functions. with the available info think of making it a micros service.but validate whether the it fits your need.

Comment: @Hack I am not against using dll/lib. Its just I want expose a chunk of code (which does common tasks) to all 5 platforms/ projects. Eg: Dispaying student info on all 5 platforms and many more things like this.

Comment: In that case I would recommend just moving the common code into a Dll then. Of course depending on exactly what your doing there may be better solution, but I'm just going on the assumption you need just a worker class of some sort doing stuff.  You mention that 90% of the code is the same.  If you find that some classes are very close to the same but have a few different methods, then you can create abstract classes and just create objects in each project that use the base methods when they don't need to be modified.